# Cartthrob MSM Sagepay 5006 error

Tags: cartthrob, multi-site-manager, sagepay

I have a Cartthrob MSM installation (2 stores) that use sagepay (europe offsite) for processing payments.

Every time I try to make a payment through the sites, I get all the way through the payment process and at the very end I get the following error:

```
> HTTP Status Code:    500 
> HTTP Status Message: The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.
> Error Code :         5006 
> Error Description :  Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.
```

I've checked that extload.php is configured correctly, and when I output the NotificationURL value from the gateway plugin it looks correct:

```
http://mysite.com/themes/third_party/cartthrob/lib/extload.php/sage_s
```

Does anyone have any experience of this error and possible solutions? I contacted the hosts (Nexcess) who said they couldn't think of any security that might be on the server, stopping a callback from sage.

I've been trying to get these sites working for a week through a host of errors, I'm hoping this is the last hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke at length with Chris Newton (Cartthrob developer) and he eventually tracked the problem down to a combination of me using Focus Lab's [multi-environment config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config), changes in the way that EE 2.7.2 handles `$assign_to_config[]` and how this affected CT2.4. We're still working on a fix, but it looks like this was a very specific environment/config issue.